# Weird flickering bug in the latest version of Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome

After updating Google Chrome browser to the latest 15.0.874.106 version (under Windows 7), my site is experiencing some weird flickering bug.

The text shadows are displaying completely wrong, the text itself is fuzzy and unclear, some parts of code don't work anymore (e.g. right floating, fixed menu)... etc.
For a couple of seconds the site is displayed fine, then it flickers all of the sudden (while still loading) and then the rendering gets messed up. (I think it has maybe some problems with loading of Google Maps v3)

The funny thing is that the old version of Chrome (before updating, on my other computer) is still displaying the site without any problems, and there haven't been any changes in the code in the meanwhile.

In other browsers (as i said, even in the old chrome) everything is OK. Firebug and Chrome's code inspector (CTRL+SHIFT+J) don't show any errors in the code. I have been doing some digging on the Internet and here as well, and I havent't found anything useful.

You can check it out by yourself by clicking [here](http://svipopusti.hr/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After 2 days of extensive research, it seems that this problem is caused by new google chrome's accelerated-compositing feature (hardware acceleration). When I disabled it (in Win7 by entering -disable-accelerated-compositing in properties>target field) this flickering and blinking did not happen anymore.

Comment: This bug is obviously still present in the Chromium project and you can find out more about it here: http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-bugs/browse_thread/thread/4f24018ed4b337c1/b70da4bc7fc6dcf1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have done same settings changes as mentioned above post and now, that weird flicker got stopped, below are the details....

- Open Chrome Browser
- Click on Settings menu option
- Click on Advance setting link in Settings page
- Un-Check  "Use Hardware acceleration when available" checkbox
- Restart you chrome browser

Happy Browsing....... :)

Comment: I've recently updated my old iMac from OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard) to 10.7.5 (Lion) and my Chrome (latest Version 48.0.2564.97 (64-bit)) started to flicker as well! A lot of weird artifacts were flashing or Chrome kept flicking between webpage and desktop wallpaper etc. 
Turning off Hardware acceleration solved the issue!

Comment: After disabling hardware acceleration this way, scrolling is not smooth anymore and is even worse than the flickering problem.

Comment: 9 years later, still same issue, same solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to disable not only accelerated-compositing, but also accelerated-2d-canvas.

This is how I start google-chrome on Linux:

```
/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome %U --user-data-dir=/root --disable-accelerated-compositing --disable-accelerated-2d-canvas
```

On Windows, you might want to omit

```
--user-data-dir=/root
```

Answer (score 0):

Josip Filipović apology where to do that  (in Win7 by entering -`disable-accelerated-compositing` in `properties > target` field) that part disables hardware acceleration.